# Counting lengths of subseries

Tags: r

Imagine series of numbers like

```
c(21,22,23,30,31,32,34,35,36,37,38,50,NA,52)
```

where subseries are defined as: `x[t]` is a part of some subserie if `x[t] = x[t-1] + 1`?

So in the example above we have the following series:

```
c(21,22,23,30,31,32,34,35,36,37,38,50,NA,52)
## 1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3  4  -  5    # serie ID
##    3    |   3    |      5      | 1 | | 1    # length
```

What would be the most efficient way of tagging the subseries and counting their lengths (as a single function or two separate ones)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can get the difference between the adjacent elements, check whether it is equal to 1, get the cumulative sum, and use that as group to get the length of the vector

```
unname(tapply(v1, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(replace(v1, is.na(v1), 0))!=1)), length))
#[1] 3 3 5 1 1 1
```

If we need the `NA` elements as `""`

```
unname(tapply(v1, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(replace(v1, is.na(v1), 0))!=1)), 
            function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) "" else length(x)))
#[1] "3" "3" "5" "1" ""  "1"
```

---

Or a variation posted by @DavidArenburg with `rle`

```
rle(cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(replace(v1, is.na(v1), 0))!=1)))$lengths
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm accepting the answer by *akrun* (with contribution by *David Arenburg*), but for the reference I provide a **Rcpp** solution I created in the meantime.

```cpp
NumericVector cpp_seriesLengths(NumericVector x) {
  int n = x.length();
  if (n == 1)
    return wrap(1);
  NumericVector out(n);
  int tmpCount = 1;
  int prevStart = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < (n-1); i++) {
    if ( x[i] == (x[i+1] - 1) ) {
      tmpCount += 1;
    } else {
      for (int j = prevStart; j <= i; j++)
        out[j] = tmpCount;
      tmpCount = 1;
      prevStart = i+1;
    }
  }
  for (int j = prevStart; j < n; j++)
    out[j] = tmpCount;

  return out;
}
```